# Adding child view controller to my parent view controller is not working

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to add the "child_view_controller" to the "parent_view controller". I am using this for my iPad app, where the requirement is to add the another controller(child controller) to the parent controller. Moreover I have to establish the communication from the child view controller to the parent view controller for which I am using notification. But the child view controller in not getting added up. I am posting the code.

```css
-(void)addPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController storyBoardId:(NSString *)stroyBoardId withFrame:(CGRect)frame contact:(NgnContact *)contact
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyBoardId];
    viewController.view.frame = frame;
    //viewController.contactToSendChat=contact;
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"cpdc_check_embed"]) {
        self.checkVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

...where checkVC is a property on the container controller:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) <Viewcontroller name> * checkVC;
```

You just have to set your embed segue's Storyboard ID to whatever you want (in this case, cpdc_check_embed):

[image]

..and then check the identifier in -prepareForSegue:sender:.

Still not an outlet, but cleaner than Matt's (IMHO) and more specific than Caleb's, and you still get a nice-looking storyboard:

[image]